# How would I use HTMLAgilityPack to extract the value I want

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

For the given HTML I want the value of `id`

```
 <div class="name" id="john-5745844">
 <div class="name" id="james-6940673">
```

**UPDATE** 
This is what I have at the moment

```
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.Load(new StringReader(pageResponse));
    HtmlNode root = htmlDoc.DocumentNode;

    List<string> anchorTags = new List<string>();
    foreach (HtmlNode div in root.SelectNodes("//div[@class='name' and @id]"))
    {
        HtmlAttribute att = div.Attributes["id"];
        Console.WriteLine(att.Value);
    }
```

The error I am getting is at the `foreach` line stating: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I believe the this part is wrong `"//div[@class='name' and @id]"`

Comment: That XPath code should load all divs with class "name" and which contain the id attribute.  Is the HTML static?  Or generated with js?

Comment: @NickAldwin the original html is more complicated and I think in trying to simplify the problem, it affected the solution. Im trying to include the original html now.

Comment: How do I tell if the HTML is static or generated with js? Looking at it again, your XPath query should be correct

Comment: Found my mistake, I was referencing a previous html string *smacks head*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from the examples page:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm"); //or whatever HTML file you have
foreach(HtmlNode div in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='name' and @id]")
{
   HtmlAttribute att = div["id"];
   //Do something with att.Value
}
```